# Group by Totals SQL for week ending numbers; monthly; year to date numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am having trouble right way to group by totals for week ending, month to date and year to date. Currently with my query, I get this output

```
(No column name)        Received App #  Received App $  (No column name)    Loan Closed #   Loan Closed $
Applications Received   2               $500,000.00     New Loans Closed    1               $250,000.00
```

Instead of above, I would like to get my output like this

```
Applications Received 2  $500,000.00 
New Loans Closed      1  $250,000.00
```

Please see my query below:

```
    select 

    'Applications Received',
    count(case when pd.Status_four_Dt between '1/1/2014' and '2/1/2014' then pd.loan_amt end) as 'Received App #',
    sum(case when pd.Status_four_Dt between '1/1/2014' and '2/1/2014' then pd.loan_amt end) as 'Received App $',
    'New Loans Closed',
    count(case when pd.Status_ten_Dt between '1/1/2014' and '2/1/2014' then pd.loan_amt end) as 'Loan Closed #',
    sum(case when pd.Status_ten_Dt between '1/1/2014' and '2/1/2014' then pd.loan_amt end) as 'Loan Closed $'


    from pipe_deal pd
     left join pipe_quote pq
     on pd.id = pq.deal_id

where
pd.record_type_lkup ='dl'
and pd.company_identity_id = 2
and ((pd.status_lkup_id in(14,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23) and pq.active_yn = 'y') or (pd.status_lkup_id = 13 and pq.active_yn is null) or (pd.status_lkup_id = 24 and (pq.active_yn = 'y' or pq.active_yn is null)))
and pd.delete_yn = 'N'
and pd.Status_One_Dt > '01/01/2008'
and (pd.EMP_OFFICE_LKUP_Id <> 192 or pd.EMP_OFFICE_LKUP_Id is null) 


--group by
--(case 
--when pd.Status_four_Dt>0  then 'Received Application'
--when  pd.Status_ten_Dt>0 then 'Loans Closed' 
--end)
```

So basically Applications Received and New Loans Closed totals the number for week ending for the previous week, I am just not able to group it in a way that the output should like 
Applications Received   2   $500,000.00 
New Loans Closed    1   $250,000.00

I want a way to group applications received and new loans closed where they are put in rows instead of columns.

Please help.

Comment: 1. Use proper DATE/TIME data types for dates and times.

Comment: Once you've completed step 1 above, consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET. And are you using MySQL or M$SQL?

Comment: [Please tag correctly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207274/suggested-tags-both-sql-server-and-mysql-are-suggested-by-the-system).

Comment: I am using MS SQL R2......the desired result set is provided above....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar enough with the structure of your data to give you the exact query, but you can accomplish this using UNION ALL.

You'll want to select only the applications received data  (which would appear to be COUNT(*) and SUM(pd.loan_amt) WHERE pd.Status_four_Dt BETWEEN etc) and then union that result with the one that gives you the the one that gives you the applications (which appears to be COUNT(*) and SUM(pd.loan_amt) WHERE pd.Status_ten_Dt between... etc). You can select just text for your first column, eg, "Applications Received" AS Description, COUNT(*) and SUM(loan amount) WHERE pd.Status_four_Dt BETWEEN etc and then union that result with the one for the new loans closed.

Make sense?

Comment: Basically the Received Application and Loans Closed data are dates, so lets say if i want to see how many applications were received i would filter received application column in the data set and pick only the dates for the last week or the month.... hope this is insightful for understanding the data a bit more...

Comment: Okay... so write a query that just gives you the applications received. Write another one that just gives you the loans closed. Union the queries together and you're done.